# Bind, publish, unbind, repeat

Tags: python, messaging, zeromq, pyzmq

**peer.py**

```
import zmq
import time


if __name__ == '__main__':
    context = zmq.Context()

    socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)

    while True:
        print "I: Publishing"

        socket.bind("tcp://*:5555")
        socket.send_multipart(['general', 'Unique peer information'])
        socket.unbind("tcp://*:5555")

        time.sleep(1)
```

**scanner.py**

```
import zmq


if __name__ == '__main__':
    context = zmq.Context()

    socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'general')
    socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5555")

    print "I: Scanning 5555"

    while True:
        message = socket.recv_multipart()
        print "I: Receiving: {}".format(message)
```

---

I'm attempting to broadcast multiple peers over the same port, on the same computer and have a single "scanner" listen in and "see" who is available. Each peer would broadcast its contact information, a client would then use the scanner to find out who is available and then use the broadcasted information to connect via a REQ/REP channel.

To make this work, I've attempted to quickly bind a PUB socket, broadcast information about a peer, and then unbind so as to let other peers bind to the same socket, at a different time, and broadcast a different set of identifiers for the next peer.

I'm suspecting that messages get discarded before getting sent due to the unbinding (the same occurs with a call to `close()`) but I can't figure out how to get it to empty the queue prior to closing the connection so as to not discard any messages.

Any ideas?

- Windows 8.1 x64
- Python 2.7.7 x64
- PyZMQ 4.0.4

#### Edit

I asked the same question on the ZMQ mailing-list and got some interesting replies, see here: http://lists.zeromq.org/pipermail/zeromq-dev/2014-June/026444.html

Answer (score 1):

A subscriber has to connect to the publisher for it to receive any messages.  The order of operations has to be something like the following:

1. Start the publisher ("start" means define the socket and bind or connect it, and for the subscriber, subscribe to the messages you want.
2. Start the subscriber (1 and 2 can happen in any order)
3. Send/Receive your message
4. Spin everything down

`PUB` sockets are non-blocking, they won't wait until there's a subscriber to send to, it'll just move it through the queue, and if a subscriber isn't waiting for it, it'll discard it.  [Check out the pyzmq pub/sub examples](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/tree/master/examples/pubsub), you'll see that the subscriber has to announce itself before the publisher can send a message and know it'll be received.

You can fake it with a timeout, if you know your subscriber *will always* be available within a specified period of time, otherwise pub/sub won't work for you.

So, what's happening is that your `PUB` socket binds, but it takes a non-zero amount of time for your subscriber to connect, even if you spun it up first, so it's not ready when you send your message.  The message gets discarded, and then you spin everything down, still likely before the subscriber has a chance to connect completely.

You'll need to use a different kind of socket pair, perhaps `rep/req`, but you're looking for blocking behavior that will hold a message until the receiver is ready to receive it.  This could mean using a central server that controls the information about which peers are available rather than attempting to broadcast the info to all peers, or something else depending on your messaging needs and architecture.  Alternatively, you'll need a longer-lived pub/sub system.

Comment: Thanks Jason, just to make sure we're both on the same page, each peer is meant to sit idly by and publish messages. They would each be long-running (hours, days) whereas the scanner would be short-lived (seconds, minutes).

Comment: I edited my question to add a link to the ZMQ mailing list where I posted an example based on feedback that I think would work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on feedback over on the ZMQ mailing list, here's the suggestion I'm going with until something more suited comes along. The problem that remains is how I can only ever have 1 scanner running at any point in time. Ideally, scanners would be independent of peers and each other.

Thoughts?

**peer.py**

```
import zmq
import time
import uuid

unique_id = uuid.uuid4().get_urn()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    while True:
        print "I: Publishing {}".format(unique_id)

        context = zmq.Context()
        socket = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
        socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555")
        socket.send_multipart(['general', unique_id])
        socket.close()
        context.destroy()

        # Wait for a random amount of time
        time.sleep(1)
```

**scanner.py**

```
import zmq

if __name__ == '__main__'
:
    context = zmq.Context()

    socket = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
    socket.bind("tcp://*:5555")


print "I: Scanning 5555"

    while True:
        message = socket.recv_multipart()
        print "I: Receiving: {}".format(message)
```